# how to parse a list (represented as a string) in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Using Pyspark I am loading a parquet file which has a very simple structure:

```
root
 |-- mydata: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamps: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mylist: string (nullable = true)
```

The problem is that `mylist` was originally a list in python, which has been represented into a string. So the first element looks like

`['first', 'second', 'third']`

How can I represent this column as a proper list-column (a struct?) so that I can access its nth element and explode it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `from_json` and pass the parsing format.

here's an example

```py
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(1, '["first", "second", "third"]')]).toDF(['id', 'mylist']). \
    withColumn('parsed_mylist', func.from_json('mylist', 'array<string>')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+----------------------------+----------------------+
# |id |mylist                      |parsed_mylist         |
# +---+----------------------------+----------------------+
# |1  |["first", "second", "third"]|[first, second, third]|
# +---+----------------------------+----------------------+

# root
#  |-- id: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- mylist: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- parsed_mylist: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```